# batch processing mail with phpmailer class

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, batch-processing

I need to setup a batch processing mailings with phpmailer class.
My web site is already sending mails thru phpmailer but according to my shared server I need batch processing system for my email campaigns. for ex: 100 mails per hour. this should happen automatic when the admin select the list of receiver.

I need this should work with phpmailer. what further steps should I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create the phpmailer script for the email campaigns
2. Add it to a scheduler (eg, cron job if you are on a Linux server).

Comment: Add the script to the Windows task scheduler.